# Talend - Extract FileName from tLogRow/tSort

Tags: talend

I am new to Talend and just trying to work my way through it.

**Problem Statement** 
I need to process a positional file, from a list of files. Need to identify the latest file first and then process only that file. I was able to identify the most updated file. And then I was able to create another flow which processes the positional file. The problem is combining these two flows so that I am able to identify the most recent file and have just that one processed.

**Tried so far**
Have been trying to extract the most recent file from a list within a directory. Iterated through all the files, retained their properties in a buffer. Post completion of this sub-task, read through the buffer, sorted with descending mime, extracted the top record and was able to print it using tLogRow.

All seems to be fine except I don't know how to use the filename now for next task.

I am certain this is very rudimentary but I'll be honest, I've been scourging the internet/help from quite some time now, with no success.

Any pointers would help.

The job flow is attached for your reference.

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to help if you gave some details about what you are trying to achieve once you’ve read these file names etc.

Comment: My bad, I wasn't verbose enough. I need to process a positional file, from a list of files. Need to identify the latest file first and then process only that file.

I was able to identify the most updated file. And then I was able to create another flow which processes the positional file.

The problem is combining these two flows so that I am able to identify the most recent file and have just that one processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can simplify your job by using `tFileList`'s capabilities. It can sort files by their modified date:

[image]

Next, use `tIterateToFlow` to convert each iteration to a row:

```
(String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEPATH")
```

and `tSampleRow` with a range of "1", to get the most recent file.

Then store the result in a global variable. In the next subjob, just use that global variable as your filename in `tFileInputPositional`.

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful. The simplification of the flow is certainly appreciated. I was able to fix the flow with your recommendation and learnt few things while doing that. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad to be of help :)